# Sliding closet door channel screws not holding

Tags: repair, door-frame

How do I get the slider door channel screws to hold? They keep spinning no matter how much I screw them in. It is a metal frame wardrobe slider door that has a metal channel on the top.

[image]

Comment: What's in the wall? That's the critical bit that you haven't shared. Is it stripped wood or something else? How long are the screws? What finish is on the walls and how thick is it?

Comment: That screw coming out looks like a fine thread.  You might need wood screws with a coarser thread (assuming it's going into a wood stud in the first place.)

Comment: Ken, that looks like what comes with most such kits. It'll hold in wood just fine, assuming it has proper penetration (> 1").

Comment: Seems to me that there's enough info here... Most likely, the OP stripped out the wood or hit something solid. Both have been addressed in answers provided. A simply up vote and check mark click will tell us which of the proposed solutions took care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've stripped out the screw holes. You need to glue some wood back in there for the screw to bite into (toothpicks are a classic solution) or insert the screws in a different place.

(There are commercial products which are a trifle more elegant but usually not more effective.)

Addressing Isherwood's points:

Yes, longer screw would be an good alternative if there is still solid wood farther up. I've seen repeated repair attempts work their way through a 2x4, but usually there will be something behind the trim that you can reach and bite into.

Moving the screw a bit: Thought about mentioning that. Decided to assume that this had already been attempted, along with looking at using another screw hole in the track if there is one, and that there isn't room to remove all the screws and shift the entire track, and that the idea of boring and possibly countersinking new mounting holes therein had likewise been considered and rejected. You've right, I should have pointed those out too.

Comment: I don't know why you'd do that rather than using a longer screw or just moving the screw a bit. Location isn't particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have either hit a nail plate or a nail.  Try a fine drill bit, If it can't go through or encounters resistance, then you have hit some metal.

In which case see if you use another hole in the channel, or drill another hole in the channel, a few inches away from this one.